# How to use or/and in dplyr to subset a data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to subset a data.frame with a combination of or/and. This is my code using normal R function.

```
df <- expand.grid(list(A = seq(1, 5), B = seq(1, 5), C = seq(1, 5)))
df$value <- seq(1, nrow(df))

df[(df$A == 1 & df$B == 3) |
    (df$A == 3 & df$B == 2),]
```

How could I convert them using filter function in dplyr package? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### `dplyr` solution:

load library:

`library(dplyr)`

filter with condition as above:

`df %>% filter(A == 1 & B == 3 | A == 3 & B ==2)`

Answer (score 12):

You could use `subset()` and `[` as well.  Here are some different methods and their respective benchmarks on a larger data set.

```
df <- expand.grid(A = 1:100, B = 1:100, C = 1:100)
df$value <- 1:nrow(df)

library(dplyr); library(microbenchmark)
f1 <- function() subset(df, A == 1 & B == 3 | A == 3 & B == 2)
f2 <- function() filter(df, A == 1 & B == 3 | A == 3 & B == 2)
f3 <- function() df[with(df, A == 1 & B == 3 | A == 3 & B == 2), ]
f4 <- function() df[(df$A == 1 & df$B == 3) | (df$A == 3 & df$B == 2),]

microbenchmark(subset = f1(), filter = f2(), with = f3(), "$" = f4())
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  subset 47.42671 49.99802 75.95385 92.24430 96.05960 141.2964   100
#  filter 36.94019 38.77325 60.22831 42.64112 84.35896 155.0145   100
#    with 38.90918 44.36299 71.29214 86.39629 88.89008 134.7670   100
#       $ 40.22723 44.08606 71.32186 86.71372 89.59275 133.1132   100
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know there was such a difference between `with()` and `$`.

Comment: I keep getting worse results with filter():
`Unit: microseconds
 expr    median 
 f1()  511.0195 
 f2() 1725.4910 
 f3()  362.2040 
 f4()  489.8515 
`
R: 3.1.1
dplyr 0.3.0.2

Comment: @docendodiscimus - There isn't.  This was a bad benchmark ;)  Edited

Comment: `neval = 100` is not enough. I have made multiple tests with larger datasets (5k rows) and `neval = 1000` which does not agree to say which one is faster between `subset`, `filter` and `[`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I was trying to see the difference in terms of the resulting dataset and I coulnd't get an explanation to why the good old "[" operator behaved differently:

```
# Subset for year=2013
sub<-brfss2013 %>% filter(iyear == "2013")
dim(sub)
#[1] 486088    330
length(which(is.na(sub$iyear))==T)
#[1] 0

sub2<-filter(brfss2013, iyear == "2013")
dim(sub2)
#[1] 486088    330
length(which(is.na(sub2$iyear))==T)
#[1] 0

sub3<-brfss2013[brfss2013$iyear=="2013", ]
dim(sub3)
#[1] 486093    330
length(which(is.na(sub3$iyear))==T)
#[1] 5

sub4<-subset(brfss2013, iyear=="2013")
dim(sub4)
#[1] 486088    330
length(which(is.na(sub4$iyear))==T)
#[1] 0
```