# CSV order preserved in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, subset

The order of my data is important. If I load a CSV into R using `read.csv`, is the order of the rows in the dataframe *guaranteed* to match that of the CSV?

How about if I load a bunch of CSVs and `rbind` them together and then use `subset` to get at the data I'm interested in?

For example:

**1.csv**

```
foo,bar
a,123
a,456
c,789
```

**2.csv**

```
foo,bar
d,987
a,999
b,654
a,321
```

Will the following:

```
data1<-read.csv("1.csv", header=T)
data2<-read.csv("2.csv", header=T)
all_data<-rbind(data1, data2)
filtered<-subset(all_data, foo=="a")
```

...*always* produce a `filtered` as:

```
   foo  bar
1    a  123
2    a  456
3    a  999
4    a  321
```

...and does this behaviour hold for arbitrary CSV inputs and filters?

Comment: My simple answer would be yes to all questions.

Comment: The reason I ask is because I'm going to be doing the equivalent of a SQL join, but there is no key and so I can only rely on ordering (where the other data is in the same relative order as the first)

Comment: I understand. R won't change row order when reading or binding.

Comment: @PauloMiraMor Nor subsetting?

Comment: Probably a silly question - I'm sure you have your reasons - but, why can't you add an ID/key column?

Comment: @user127649 That's my backup plan, but if R preserves order, then that would be a quicker/easier win

Comment: Fair enough, I was just curious. Though I would say adding a key would be safer because you could always regain the correct order no matter what manipulations/accidents occurred in the future

Comment: @user127649 You're preaching to the choir...but this particular choir is very lazy ;)

Comment: @user1494080 I'm confused. Do you want a contributor to R's source code to reiterate what Paulo said in the first comment ? If you need more convincing you could look at the source code, `read.csv` calls `read.table`, `read.table` calls `scan`, scan reads a file or a connection and parses it. There's no row shuffling happening anywhere, it would be a huge issue if it did. However you could have empty lines in your CSV and those will be skipped if you keep `blank.lines.skip` set to TRUE, in this case your `data.frame` might be `shorter` than your csv.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Thanks. The question is whether it is _guaranteed_ that the order is preserved. Implementations can change. The hope was that there is a note somewhere in the specification/documentation.

Comment: The doc says `Reads a file in table format and creates a data frame from it, with cases corresponding to lines and variables to fields in the file.`. I don't think the `R` doc guarantees anything anywhere, and nobody can be held legally responsible if something goes wrong (I think it's the favorite argument from proprietary software proponents), but your question is a bit like asking if `max` will always return the maximum, if it stops doing so pretty much all the R code of the world will break. As long as you stick to base R functions and major releases you're safe beyond a reasonable doubt.

Comment: You can add extra safety by calling explicitly `utils::read.csv`, `base::subset` and `base::rbind` so they can't be masked by a treacherous function. And about `subset` you might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/why-is-better-than-subset

Answer (score 4):

Have a read through the source code for `read.table`. It uses the `scan` base function, which itself uses the `file` and `textConnection` functions. All of these appear to point toward you being able to read in data sequentially ("line" by "line" based on delimiter) and feeding it in.

```
function (file, header = FALSE, sep = "", quote = "\"'", dec = ".", 
    numerals = c("allow.loss", "warn.loss", "no.loss"), row.names, 
    col.names, as.is = !stringsAsFactors, na.strings = "NA", 
    colClasses = NA, nrows = -1, skip = 0, check.names = TRUE, 
    fill = !blank.lines.skip, strip.white = FALSE, blank.lines.skip = TRUE, 
    comment.char = "#", allowEscapes = FALSE, flush = FALSE, 
    stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors(), fileEncoding = "", 
    encoding = "unknown", text, skipNul = FALSE) 
{
    if (missing(file) && !missing(text)) {
        file <- textConnection(text, encoding = "UTF-8")
        encoding <- "UTF-8"
        on.exit(close(file))
    }
    if (is.character(file)) {
        file <- if (nzchar(fileEncoding)) 
            file(file, "rt", encoding = fileEncoding)
        else file(file, "rt")
        on.exit(close(file))
    }
    if (!inherits(file, "connection")) 
        stop("'file' must be a character string or connection")
    if (!isOpen(file, "rt")) {
        open(file, "rt")
        on.exit(close(file))
    }
    pbEncoding <- if (encoding %in% c("", "bytes", "UTF-8")) 
        encoding
    else "bytes"
    numerals <- match.arg(numerals)
    if (skip > 0L) 
        readLines(file, skip)
    nlines <- n0lines <- if (nrows < 0L) 
        5
    else min(5L, (header + nrows))
    lines <- .External(C_readtablehead, file, nlines, comment.char, 
        blank.lines.skip, quote, sep, skipNul)
    if (encoding %in% c("UTF-8", "latin1")) 
        Encoding(lines) <- encoding
    nlines <- length(lines)
    if (!nlines) {
        if (missing(col.names)) 
            stop("no lines available in input")
        rlabp <- FALSE
        cols <- length(col.names)
    }
    else {
        if (all(!nzchar(lines))) 
            stop("empty beginning of file")
        if (nlines < n0lines && file == 0L) {
            pushBack(c(lines, lines, ""), file, encoding = pbEncoding)
            on.exit((clearPushBack(stdin())))
        }
        else pushBack(c(lines, lines), file, encoding = pbEncoding)
        first <- scan(file, what = "", sep = sep, quote = quote, 
            nlines = 1, quiet = TRUE, skip = 0, strip.white = TRUE, 
            blank.lines.skip = blank.lines.skip, comment.char = comment.char, 
            allowEscapes = allowEscapes, encoding = encoding, 
            skipNul = skipNul)
        col1 <- if (missing(col.names)) 
            length(first)
        else length(col.names)
        col <- numeric(nlines - 1L)
        if (nlines > 1L) 
            for (i in seq_along(col)) col[i] <- length(scan(file, 
                what = "", sep = sep, quote = quote, nlines = 1, 
                quiet = TRUE, skip = 0, strip.white = strip.white, 
                blank.lines.skip = blank.lines.skip, comment.char = comment.char, 
                allowEscapes = allowEscapes, encoding = encoding, 
                skipNul = skipNul))
        cols <- max(col1, col)
        rlabp <- (cols - col1) == 1L
        if (rlabp && missing(header)) 
            header <- TRUE
        if (!header) 
            rlabp <- FALSE
        if (header) {
            .External(C_readtablehead, file, 1L, comment.char, 
                blank.lines.skip, quote, sep, skipNul)
            if (missing(col.names)) 
                col.names <- first
            else if (length(first) != length(col.names)) 
                warning("header and 'col.names' are of different lengths")
        }
        else if (missing(col.names)) 
            col.names <- paste0("V", 1L:cols)
        if (length(col.names) + rlabp < cols) 
            stop("more columns than column names")
        if (fill && length(col.names) > cols) 
            cols <- length(col.names)
        if (!fill && cols > 0L && length(col.names) > cols) 
            stop("more column names than columns")
        if (cols == 0L) 
            stop("first five rows are empty: giving up")
    }
    if (check.names) 
        col.names <- make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE)
    if (rlabp) 
        col.names <- c("row.names", col.names)
    nmColClasses <- names(colClasses)
    if (is.null(nmColClasses)) {
        if (length(colClasses) < cols) 
            colClasses <- rep_len(colClasses, cols)
    }
    else {
        tmp <- rep_len(NA_character_, cols)
        names(tmp) <- col.names
        i <- match(nmColClasses, col.names, 0L)
        if (any(i <= 0L)) 
            warning("not all columns named in 'colClasses' exist")
        tmp[i[i > 0L]] <- colClasses[i > 0L]
        colClasses <- tmp
    }
    what <- rep.int(list(""), cols)
    names(what) <- col.names
    colClasses[colClasses %in% c("real", "double")] <- "numeric"
    known <- colClasses %in% c("logical", "integer", "numeric", 
        "complex", "character", "raw")
    what[known] <- sapply(colClasses[known], do.call, list(0))
    what[colClasses %in% "NULL"] <- list(NULL)
    keep <- !sapply(what, is.null)
    data <- scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
        dec = dec, nmax = nrows, skip = 0, na.strings = na.strings, 
        quiet = TRUE, fill = fill, strip.white = strip.white, 
        blank.lines.skip = blank.lines.skip, multi.line = FALSE, 
        comment.char = comment.char, allowEscapes = allowEscapes, 
        flush = flush, encoding = encoding, skipNul = skipNul)
    nlines <- length(data[[which.max(keep)]])
    if (cols != length(data)) {
        warning("cols = ", cols, " != length(data) = ", length(data), 
            domain = NA)
        cols <- length(data)
    }
    if (is.logical(as.is)) {
        as.is <- rep_len(as.is, cols)
    }
    else if (is.numeric(as.is)) {
        if (any(as.is < 1 | as.is > cols)) 
            stop("invalid numeric 'as.is' expression")
        i <- rep.int(FALSE, cols)
        i[as.is] <- TRUE
        as.is <- i
    }
    else if (is.character(as.is)) {
        i <- match(as.is, col.names, 0L)
        if (any(i <= 0L)) 
            warning("not all columns named in 'as.is' exist")
        i <- i[i > 0L]
        as.is <- rep.int(FALSE, cols)
        as.is[i] <- TRUE
    }
    else if (length(as.is) != cols) 
        stop(gettextf("'as.is' has the wrong length %d  != cols = %d", 
            length(as.is), cols), domain = NA)
    do <- keep & !known
    if (rlabp) 
        do[1L] <- FALSE
    for (i in (1L:cols)[do]) {
        data[[i]] <- if (is.na(colClasses[i])) 
            type.convert(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec, 
                numerals = numerals, na.strings = character(0L))
        else if (colClasses[i] == "factor") 
            as.factor(data[[i]])
        else if (colClasses[i] == "Date") 
            as.Date(data[[i]])
        else if (colClasses[i] == "POSIXct") 
            as.POSIXct(data[[i]])
        else methods::as(data[[i]], colClasses[i])
    }
    compactRN <- TRUE
    if (missing(row.names)) {
        if (rlabp) {
            row.names <- data[[1L]]
            data <- data[-1L]
            keep <- keep[-1L]
            compactRN <- FALSE
        }
        else row.names <- .set_row_names(as.integer(nlines))
    }
    else if (is.null(row.names)) {
        row.names <- .set_row_names(as.integer(nlines))
    }
    else if (is.character(row.names)) {
        compactRN <- FALSE
        if (length(row.names) == 1L) {
            rowvar <- (1L:cols)[match(col.names, row.names, 0L) == 
                1L]
            row.names <- data[[rowvar]]
            data <- data[-rowvar]
            keep <- keep[-rowvar]
        }
    }
    else if (is.numeric(row.names) && length(row.names) == 1L) {
        compactRN <- FALSE
        rlabp <- row.names
        row.names <- data[[rlabp]]
        data <- data[-rlabp]
        keep <- keep[-rlabp]
    }
    else stop("invalid 'row.names' specification")
    data <- data[keep]
    if (is.object(row.names) || !(is.integer(row.names))) 
        row.names <- as.character(row.names)
    if (!compactRN) {
        if (length(row.names) != nlines) 
            stop("invalid 'row.names' length")
        if (anyDuplicated(row.names)) 
            stop("duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed")
        if (anyNA(row.names)) 
            stop("missing values in 'row.names' are not allowed")
    }
    class(data) <- "data.frame"
    attr(data, "row.names") <- row.names
    data
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a basic code that you can use to double check results coming from `read.csv` and `subset`:

**Compare `read.csv` with `readLines`**

Here you have a code that compare the result coming from `read.csv` with `readLines` (function reading line by line a file)

```
  library("readr" )
  library("rlist")
  file1<-file.choose() #Select your csv file1
  file2<-file.choose() #Select your csv file2

  #readLines
  input_list<-strsplit(readLines(file1),",")
  db_readLines<-data.frame(list.rbind(input_list[2:length(input_list)]))
  names(db_readLines)<-input_list[[1]]

  #readd.csv
  db_readcsv<-read.csv(file1,header = T,sep = ",")

  #Comparison
  if ((sum(db_readcsv==db_readLines)/(nrow(db_readcsv)*ncol(db_readcsv)))==1)
  {
    cat("Same data.frame")
  } else
  {
    cat("Data.frames are differents")
  }
```

You can use it with your csv file to compare results and verify that `read.csv` preserves lines order as `readLines`.

**Compare `subset` with `rbind` + basic filtering**

About the second part of the question another easy test:

```
data1<-read.csv(file1, header=T,sep=",")
  data2<-read.csv(file2, header=T,sep=",")
  all_data<-rbind(data1, data2)
  filtered1<-subset(all_data, foo=="a")

  filtered2<-rbind(data1[data1$foo=="a",],data2[data2$foo=="a",])

  #Comparison
  if ((sum(filtered1==filtered2)/(nrow(filtered2)*ncol(filtered2)))==1)
  {
    cat("Same data.frame")
  } else
  {
    cat("Data.frames are differents")
  }
```

You can include this kind of tests in your code, but obviously this is inefficient and redundant.

Answer (score 3):

It is safe to assume that all of those functions (`read.csv`, `rbind`, and `subset`) are guaranteed to preserve the order of your data as in the original csv.

Personally, I prefer using `dplyr::filter` over `base::subset`. As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882463/difference-between-subset-and-filter-from-dplyr) answer the two work almost identically. The main difference is that `subset` comes with a warning in `?subset`: "This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like `[`, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences." `filter` is designed to work robustly with the rest of `dplyr` and the `tidyverse`, both interactively and programmatically, and has a separate standard evaluation version `filter_` for when necessary.. So perhaps `filter` is a safer bet, especially if you're already using the `dplyr` framework. The only disadvantage to `filter` that I've encountered is that it does not keep rownames, while `subset` does.

Either way, I really don't think you need to worry about rows being reshuffled. In my experience, all of these functions have always produced R objects ordered in terms of the original data. If you want to be ultra-careful, it wouldn't hurt to go with @user127649's suggestion and add a unique ID column as a back up. I'm always in favor of lazier options, but it might be worth peace of mind!