# How to subset items in a list

Tags: r, list, subset, vectorization

Consider.

```
li <- list(c(1,1,1), c(2,1,1), c(5,1,0))
## [[1]]
## [1] 1 1 1                <-- 0 modulo 3
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 2 1 1
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] 5 1 0                <--- 0 modulo 3
```

I want to keep all items in the list whose sum modulo 3 equals zero (or some other logical expression regarding the item in the list).

Code.

```
  new <- list()
  idx <- 1
  for (i in seq_along(li) ) {
    nxt <- li[[i]]
    if ((sum(nxt) %% 3) == 0) {
      new[idx] <- list(nxt)
      idx <- idx + 1
    } 
  }
## new
## [[1]]
## [1] 1 1 1
##
## [[2]]
## [1] 5 1 0
```

However. I would like a vectorized solution.
I tried.

```
new <- subset(li, lapply(li, (sum %% 3) == 0 ))
```

but to no avail.

**Edit**
See also [Difference between subset and filter from dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882463/difference-between-subset-and-filter-from-dplyr) for more detailed information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Base R:

```
Filter(\(x)!sum(x)%%3, li)
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 5 1 0
```

in tidyverse

```
purrr::keep(li, ~!sum(.x)%%3)
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 5 1 0

purrr::discard(li, ~!!sum(.x)%%3) # !0
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 5 1 0
```