# Is there an R function to pick only certain row value combinations?

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
my_data <- data.frame( 
   letter = c("x","x","x","x","x","y","y","y","y","z","z","z","z"),
   number = c(1,5,6,7,2,3,4,5,6,1,4,4,4))
```

I now wish to make a new data_frame where only a certain picked combination of the columns exists ("x" can be 1,2 "y" can be 3 and "z" can be 4), so it will give something like this:

```
my_data2 <- data.frame( 
   letter = c("x","x","y","z","z"),
   number = c(1,2,3,4,4))
```

I can do this by if-else, but is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Hi Sofie, your initial data frame was incomplete and I guessed what last value there should be. Also your logic is unclear as to how you go from the initial data set to the outcome. What is this "certain pick combination"?

Answer (score 0):

```
my_data <- data.frame( 
  letter = c("x","x","x","x","x","y","y","y","y","z","z","z","z"),
  number = c(1,5,6,7,2,3,4,5,6,1,4,4,4))

library(tidyverse)
my_data %>% filter(letter == "x" & number %in% c(1,2) | 
                   letter == "y" & number == 3 |
                   letter == "z" & number == 4
                   )

  letter number
1      x      1
2      x      2
3      y      3
4      z      4
5      z      4
6      z      4
```

[How to use or/and in dplyr to subset a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319747/how-to-use-or-and-in-dplyr-to-subset-a-data-frame)